# Cannot redeclare class User in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, administrator

The source of this error is the administrator package maintained by frozennode.

**Error:**

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
 Cannot redeclare class User
```

**Reference:**

```
 open: /home/itrekker/public_html/app/models/User.php
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

 class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = "user";
    protected $hidden = ["password"];
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
```

When this error is returned I don't have a trail of functions to follow to the original cause of the error. I just have this error and prior to this error I see:

```
 0. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown
 <#unknown>0
```

---

It seems apparent that this package must already have a classes called User since using the package is the only thing that breaks the site, however when I try to apply what I believed would be the solution  (renaming my user model to User mod and a few other attempted variants)  I get the same error just with a different model name.

Comment: Do you have another `User` class (more than one) available in your project, it obvious because of the error message `Cannot redeclare class User`.

Comment: After renaming the User model, did you do a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I have a very similar issue.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` helped in my case